# SP2010 Search: Managed Property on lookup column returns "ID" instead of "Title"

Tags: 2010, lookup-column, search-results, enterprise-search

I've got a document library named "Documentation" and a user defined list named "Suppliers".

"Documentation" has a lookup column linked to "Suppliers":

- WAWI(text) -> linked to "Suppliers:Title"

There is a Managed Property named "TrWAWI" mapped to the Crawled Properties "WAWI" and "ows_WAWI" ("Include values from all crawled properties mapped") as described in this blog post (["How to crawl Lookup field or column"](http://www.sharepoint-insight.com/2008/10/05/how-to-crawl-lookup-field-or-column/)).

When I'm searching (keyword query) for documents from the library "Documentation" the Managed Property TrWAWI returns WAWI:Title as desired. But certain "Suppliers" are only shown with their WAWI:ID (see screenshot from "Mossman's FAST for Sharepoint Query Tool").

[image: screenshot from Mossman's FAST for Sharepoint Query Tool]

I want the Managed Property to always display the WAWI:Title instead of WAWI:ID, e.g. "F2025" instead of "2". Any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the attribute "Include values from all crawled properties mapped", if you are including the ID it will be included in the results. Remove the field from the mapping list and recrawl the content. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Thanks Matthew. I've changed the mapping of the managed property to "Include values from a single crawled property based on the order specified" and took care that the "ows_*" properties are on top of the crawled properties list.